# client side verification using javascript textbox

Tags: javascript

I have the following Javascript code. It prevents the textbox from being empty, but I also need it to prevent numbers from being entered (I don't know how to add that)

```
if (document.getElementById('firstname').value=="") {
    errormessage+="Enter your first name \n";
    document.getElementById('firstname').style.borderColor="red";
} else {
    document.getElementById('firstname').style.borderColor="green";     
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can we get a javascript program to prevent numeric input?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7480241/how-can-we-get-a-javascript-program-to-prevent-numeric-input)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the number input by regexp type /[0-9]/ with `test` function .That will return true when any 0 from 9 is exist.

```
var val = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
if (val =="" || /[0-9]/.test(val) == true){
 // error show
}
else{

}
```