# How can I not allow numeric in input type text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want my input for Name is cannot typing number
mean it only allow letter
Now I use like this:

```
var key = e.keyCode;
 if (!((key == 8) || (key == 32) || 
    (key == 46) || (key >= 35 && key <= 40) || 
    (key >= 65 && key <= 90))) 
 {
  e.preventDefault();
 }
```

but It work on English letter only.
Thank you for every help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can we get a javascript program to prevent numeric input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7480241/how-can-we-get-a-javascript-program-to-prevent-numeric-input)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the built in pattern attribute in HTML.

```
<input type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z]" title="no numbers">
```

Comment: I know pattern="[A-Za-z]" can add other langue to it

Comment: The pattern is just RegEx, you can modify it any way you want.

Answer (score 0):

**[Try this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m859e02u/)**, it trigger's and rectifies on every input or change of the value to the control

```
$("#textbox").on("input",function(){ 
this.value=this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/gi, '')
})
```